# Python break for loop if equal to row length in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium

I'm pulling data from excel and transferring to a web page. After clicking on the first input box on the web page, values from the first row (starting at 'B2') are entered.

I'm using a for loop to tab to the next input box and enter in data from the next cell in the row. After all data are entered, I want to click a submit button and enter in data from the next row.

The problem I'm having is that I can't break out of the for loop, so it continually tabs through the page.

How can I break out of the for loop once all values in that row have been entered?

Here's the code I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\aelfont\\Documents\\python_date_test.xlsx', Sheet_name=0)

for m in df.index:
    for i in df.iloc[0, 1:11]:
        ActionChains(browser) \
            .send_keys(str(i)) \
            .perform()
        if i == (len(df[:11])):
            break
        else:
            ActionChains(browser) \
                .send_keys(Keys.TAB) \
                .perform()
```

Should I not use a for loop and instead do this?:

```
for i in df.iloc[0, 0:11]:

mea0 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_14581')
mea0.click()
mea0.send_keys(str((df['bx1'][0])) + Keys.TAB)
mea1 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_10019235')
mea1.send_keys(str((df['bx2'][0])))
mea1.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea2 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_87115')
mea2.send_keys(str((df['bx3'][0])))
mea2.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea3 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_10022483')
mea3.send_keys(str((df['bx4'][0])))
mea3.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea4 = browser.find_element_by_name('data2_10022483')
mea4.send_keys(str((df['bx5'][0])))
mea4.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea5 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_14914')
mea5.send_keys(str((df['bx6'][0])))
mea5.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea6 = browser.find_element_by_name('data2_14914')
mea6.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea7 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_10020797')
mea7.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea8 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_10020797')
mea8.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea9 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_10035152')
mea9.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea10 = browser.find_element_by_name('data1_10030275')
mea10.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
mea11 = browser.find_element_by_name('data2_10030275')
mea11.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

Comment: What is the content of `df`?

Comment: Added the context of `df` to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code below.

```
x = len(df.columns)
z = 1
n = 1
b = 1
while z < x:
    m = df.iloc[n, b]
    ActionChains(browser) \
        .send_keys(str(m)) \
        .perform()
    z = z + 1
    b = b + 1
    if z == x:
        break
    else:
        ActionChains (browser) \
            .send_keys(Keys.TAB) \
            .perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for m in df.index:
for i in range(1, 'last Column index where row ends'):  
    ActionChains(browser) \
        .send_keys(str(df.iloc[m,i])) \
        .perform()
    if i == 'last Column index where row ends':
        break
    else:
        ActionChains(browser) \
            .send_keys(Keys.TAB) \
            .perform()
```

Comment: This yields the following error: 

`for i in df.iloc[m, i+1]:
NameError: name 'i' is not defined`